# Dynamic Legend for Bar plot in loop

Tags: matlab

I am creating a bar plot in a loop

```
for i = 1:5
h = bar(data); hold on;
    if i == 5 % making legend only for the last loop
    legend(h,{'a', 'b','c','d','e'})
    end
end
```

The above code creates the legend only for the last loop data. But I wanted to make the legend for all the datas. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: can't you just remove the call to if i == 5 and it's associated end?

Comment: Aren't you just plotting the same data each time there? What is the purpose of you loop?

Comment: @Benoit , If I remove the if loop, the legend is set only for the last iteration because we use the handle  same handle 'h'.

Comment: @Dan This is the simplest form of my issue. In my actual code i will be loading the separate datas for every loop.

Comment: @user8162 I think then that you have simplified your problem too much. Please update your code to better reflect what you're doing.

Comment: I agree with @Dan. Moreover, you can assign different handles to every bar you plot, so you can manipulate their properties individually.

Comment: Is this meant to be five different sets of data plotted on one axis? If so, what is 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' - labels for each set of data? What does the created label currently look like? What do you expect/want it to look like?

Comment: The code you provided leaves a warning for extra legend entries. How about storing the handles in a vector ``h(i) = bar(data);`` Is that maybe what you want?

Comment: @Nras ...Thank you so much. Solved my problem very easily..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the format of your data (or your willingness to bring it together into a single matrix) you could just plot it like this:

```
data = rand(10,5);

figure;
bar(data);
legend({'a', 'b','c','d','e'})
```